# JSON.parse of a JSON string returning undefined Boolean value for a specific key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out a way to retrieve a Boolean value from a JSON string retrieved from an ajax query. I can access string and integer values, but any Boolean values are returned to console as *`undefined`.*

Here is my script for parsing the ajax return data.

```
success: function(data){
     let results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     var outside = results.outside;
     console.log(outside);
     if(outside){
      console.log("true");
     }
}
```

and here is an example of my JSON string:

```
{
    "glossary": "alphabet",
    "store": "Henry",
    "outside": true
}
```

I can return the string values, but not the Boolean value of `"outside"`. I know it is being retrieved by the ajax call because in testing I print `data` to the console and I can see its value as `true`.

Comment: How are you trying to use the boolean?  Could you post a quick snippet of where and how you are doing that?

Comment: How are you accessing the data? Also, what does `Object.keys(results)` say?

Comment: If you're trying to access the value from outside the "success" callback, well that's your problem.

Comment: Works on my box: https://jsfiddle.net/o4p7vb5k/1/ with both the native `JSON.parse` and jQuery's `parseJSON` methods.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I have added briefly how the boolean is used, it basically satisfies an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

from: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

so, you need to use: JSON.parse method
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 1):

`let results = JSON.parse(data);`, No?

Comment: jQuery has a JSON parser API. If it didn't, the OP would have seen an error from that.

Comment: this is correct, $.parseJSON is deprecated from jQuery 3.0.

Comment: This assumes that OP is using the latest jQuery version (which is not clearly stated), and even if they were, deprecated just means it should be avoided to use the function anymore, it's not yet removed from the code base but will be in a future update. Otherwise, an error would be thrown.